# Firebase Firestore Usage is counting incorrectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm making a fetch request to firebase from Next JS 13. and i only have 3 docs in that collection that i'm making a call to. so when i initially make the request it doesn't count as 3 reads which it should've been, but it counts as 12 reads.

this is how i'm making the fetch call

```
const getData = async () => {
    const constraints = [];

    constraints.push(limit(10));

    const blogs = collection(db, "blogPosts");
    let q = query(blogs, ...constraints);

    const qSnapshot = await getDocs(q);

    const snapper = await getCount(blogs);

    setDocCount(snapper.data().count);

    setLastVisible(qSnapshot.docs[qSnapshot.docs.length - 1]);

    const dataQ = qSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    }));

    setDatas(dataQ);
    setLoader(false);
  };

useEffect(() => {
    setLoader(true);

    setTimeout(() => {
      getData();
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

i don't know if this is happening because of the query, but i read that 1000 query is counted as 1 doc read. so why is this happening? and how can i fix this issue?

Comment: Have you check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76113326/firestore-too-much-read-on-1-document/76113699#76113699) answered by a Firebaser "Frank Puffelen".