# Why is Firestore assuming as multiple doc read while making a single doc read with Next js 13?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm fetching for 3 docs in my page with Next js 13, but Firebase is counting it as 10 doc Reads. and when redirecting to a detail page in which i only fetched a single doc it counts as 4 doc reads. (the count is unpredicted). I've even checked my code and i'm not running it inside a loop.

for a single doc read / detail page here is how i'm doing it

```
export async function page({ params: {itemid}}) {

const itemData = getItem(itemid);

  const [item] = await Promise.all([itemData]);

return (
   ... code here
)

}
```

and the getItem is as follows

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore/lite";
import { db } from "../firebase";

export default async function getItem(itemid) {
  const docRef = doc(db, "itemPosts", itemid);
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

  return docSnap.data();
}
```

maybe this is happening b/c when i'm passing the prop to a component i'm not de-structuring it. im passing the value as it is.

I'm passing it like

`<HeadTitle item={item} />`

instead of passing only the value i needed

```
<HeadTitle
 title={item.title}
 location={item.location}
 price={item.price}
/>
```

i don't know if that has an effect on it. but my firebase is counting it as multiple read for a single doc.  any Help PLEASE

Comment: Do you keep the Firestore console open while doing this? If so, keep in mind that usage by the Firestore console is also charged, and it's actually quite inefficient in the way it displays docs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76113326/firestore-too-much-read-on-1-document/76113699#76113699

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No i only opened the usage. I think it's happening in the getter file. I've put it inside of if statement and logged it. it's prompting multiple times

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as community wiki for everyone's visibility.

Fetching 1 document is not equal to 1 read. As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76113326/firestore-too-much-read-on-1-document?noredirect=1&lq=1) by Frank van Puffelen, several charged reads are happening during a document fetch (such as getting the list of collection, read the document ID, read the data for selected document, etc.)

As said by the firebaser who answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76113326/firestore-too-much-read-on-1-document?noredirect=1&lq=1) that there's definitely some room for optimization on firebase side.