# a single Firestore document is being called multiple times while fetching with Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

In my Next js 13 I'm fetching a single document with an id, but while i make a request the document read is not 1 (as it should be, coz i'm only fetching a single doc), Rather it is multiple (it depends b/n 2 - unknown eg: i recently get 8 reads per single doc). I'm following the firebase guideline as to fetching a doc.

I've created a lib folder and in there i created a getter file to fetch the data.

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore/lite";
import { db } from "../firebase";

export default async function getVehicle(vehicleid) {
  const docRef = doc(db, "vehiclePosts", vehicleid);
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

  if (docSnap.exists()) {
    console.log("Document data exists:");
    return docSnap.data();
  } else {
    console.log("Document data doesn't exists:");
  }
}
```

for the above code the console prompts multiple times. maybe it's happening here.

and in my detail page i'm calling it

```
async function VehicleGroup({ vehicleid }) {
  const vehicleData = getVehicle(vehicleid);
  const [vehicle] = await Promise.all([vehicleData]);

  return (
    // the code
  );
}

export default VehicleGroup;
```

and i'm also calling it for metadata

```
export async function generateMetadata({ params: { vehicleid } }) {

  const vehicleData = getVehicle(vehicleid);
  const [vehicle] = await Promise.all([vehicleData]);

  return {
    title: {vehicle.title},
    description: {vehicle.description}
    robots: {
      index: true,
      follow: true,
      nocache: false,
      googleBot: {
        index: true,
        follow: true,
        noimageindex: false,
      },
    },
  };
}
```

so am i not doing it right? why does firebase think that i'm calling it multiple times.

Comment: Do you keep the Firestore console open while doing this? If so, keep in mind that usage by the Firestore console is also charged, and it's actually quite inefficient in the way it displays docs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76113326/firestore-too-much-read-on-1-document/76113699#76113699

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i think the problem is where i get the vehicle. after analyzing it in the vscode console, i think it has something to do with webpack. b/c it's logging my console log message in the terminal the amount time in firebase usage meter. the error i'm getting is `[webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`

Comment: Fetching 1 document is not equal to 1 read. As answered here, several charged reads are happening during a document fetch (such as getting the list of collection, read the document ID, read the data for selected document, etc.) 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76113326/firestore-too-much-read-on-1-document?noredirect=1&lq=1

For the console log that is being prompted multiple times. You should check if getVehicle() is being called unnecessarily. For your issue with webpack, see if clearing your webpack cache files will resolve the issue. 

Hope helps.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki for better visibility.

Fetching 1 document is not equal to 1 read. As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76113326/firestore-too-much-read-on-1-document?noredirect=1&lq=1) by Frank van Puffelen, several charged reads are happening during a document fetch (such as getting the list of collection, read the document ID, read the data for selected document, etc.)

For the console log that is being prompted multiple times. You should check if getVehicle() is being called unnecessarily. For your issue with webpack, see if clearing your webpack cache files will resolve the issue.